# VSCode setting or extension for SCSS to autoformat brackets and place cursor

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

I recently changed my VSCode settings to stop suggestions and someone disabled a setting for SCSS files, where I could type

```
.example {}
```

hit return and this would automatically change to

```
.example {
  //cursor positioned here
}
```

I cannot figure out how to restore this setting, losing my mind trying to find extensions or suggestions. Please help!

Comment: Try going into your settings and search for SCSS. You will see Completion: Trigger Property Value Completion as the first response. If it is unchecked, that might be your problem.

Comment: Thanks @brad. It was already checked, so not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Specifically about your question

As mentioned in the comments by @Brad, it may be related to settings. However, the disabled setting may be in your `settings.json` file, which can have configuration not seen in the settings editor.

The easiest way to get to it is by using the command palette. The shortcut is `cmd+p` on a mac or `ctrl+p` in windows, and you can search for settings:

[image: command palette]

in the `settings.json` file, you can have language-specific settings. Look for something tied to `scss`, which would have brackets around it. My guess is that you may have one or more of these commands set to false:

[image: scss settings]

You may also need to check your workspace settings as well, because they can have settings active for a single folder. Using the command-palette again, you can find it by typing "workspace"

[image]

### A more general suggestion

I would recommend against turning off such a broad feature as code suggestions. They can be very helpful, and although this is a personal choice, learning to use them to your advantage can be highly productive in VS Code. One of the perhaps underused features of vscode is the ability to have [custom snippets for any given language](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets).

In order to achieve the behavior described in your answer, for example, I would configure a snippet like this:

```json
"StackOverflow Answer": {
    "prefix": "dotexample",
    "body": [
        ".example {",
        "\t$0",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Creates a .example selector"
}
```

Then, in any scss file I would simply type the value found in the `prefix` property above, and I would see my snippet:

[image: code snippet usage]

by using the `tab` key, I would then have those lines of code defined in the snippet, with my cursor placed in the position I want to type in:

[image]

This code took me 10 seconds to configure, and three keyboard keys to insert. If you type it often, it can be a huge productivity booster!

Anyway, like I said, personal preferences vary. But the more you learn about your IDE, the better your usage choices will be.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation Felipe. I'll test it all out.