# How can I auto format statements/function calls and place cursor in vscode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I would like to be able to auto format my code so that when I input the following (or something similar where `|` is my cursor):

```
if (condition) {|}
```

When I press 'Enter' I want it to look like this:

```
if (condition) {
  |
}
```

Currently it looks like this:

```
if (condition) {
  |}
```

I had an extension that did all of that for me, but I had to purge some extensions and I am unable to find it again. The closest question I have been able to find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70795037/vscode-setting-or-extension-for-scss-to-autoformat-brackets-and-place-cursor), but the solution did not work for me.

Whichever extension I was using also applied this to css classes, functions, variable declarations, and any other bracket/parenthesis multiline statements.

If there is some vscode setting that could do the same thing then I would be ok with that as well.

Comment: you can always write snippets that have this result or see if you already have them, they have always been snippets, maybe you have disabled suggestions

Comment: I checked to make sure I had suggestions enabled and I do. Still not working though.

Comment: I just tried and it has the behavior you want (v1.62), I have no extension for JavaScript, try it with `settings.json` cleared (Global and Workspace), what is the value of setting `editor.autoindent`

Comment: Initially `editor.autoIndent` wasn't in the `settings.json`. I added it with it set to "full" and still have the same behavior.